# Removing browser behavior for arrow keys in select element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am building a `table` like `handsontable`.That's why I am using arrow keys in the component.The problem is actualy so easy, but I couldn't solve whatever I did.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Something.">
<select >
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

When I want to focus `select` component with tab, it is focusing right, while the cursor is inside `input` component, that's okay.but if I use the arrow keys from the keyboard on select component the options are appearing.I want it to not show the options.But show the options if I click space button from keyboard.(Actually with the default browser behavior the options are already appearing with space button, but if use `$event.preventDefault()`, it is preventing. )

Open for your advices.You can click [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-infnyf) to play with the component.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `preventDefault()` to override the default behavior along with an event like `keydown`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Something.">
<select (keydown)="$event.preventDefault()">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1wzot8?file=src/app/app.component.html) in action. That being said, this goes against most if not all accessibility standards that are exposed by default by the browser for `select` elements. It would absolutely not be recommended to remove this critical functionality.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alexander Staroselsky .Actualy it is preventing all events but I need to use some keyboard events like  space event from the keyboard to select `select` component. I am editing the question again for my needs.

Comment: @seyidyagmur so the issue is just preventing the menu from opening when arrow keys are used? Are they supposed to be prevented when the menu is already opened and focused? Is there a good reason to want to prevent this element from being accessible/ARIA compliant?

Comment: @Alexander Staroselsky yes, Because I build a table like handsontable.I can move the focus with arrow keys.So, it is not comfortable being opened the select options when I use arrow keys.No, we should not prevent when the menu is already opened.Because once I click space button on select component the options are opening (it is supported by browsers).I want use arrow keys only in this scenario.